# css - add bigger shape with background-color around existing one

Tags: css, icons, background-color, font-awesome

i want to dynamically "fill" a shape with a css background-color and dont want to use images for this problem.

what i have now:

[image]

what i want to achieve ("filled" 50% with blue background-color):

[image]

my existing code is:
(HTML)

```
    <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-4x award_lvl1 award">
    <span>1</span>
</i>
```

(CSS)

```
    /* ==========================================================================
   General Award Styling
   ========================================================================== */
   .award{
    margin: 0;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50%;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;

    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
   }
   .award > span{
    font-size: 0.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: black;
    z-index: 2;
   }


/* ==========================================================================
   Awards Lvl1
   ========================================================================== */
   .award_lvl1{
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 50%, #e1e1e1 51%, #f6f6f6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(51%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

   }
```

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: interesting article, but im not sure how i can use this for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly, you can do this using the imbrication of your elements.

Give container and childs same border-radius and give a padding to container (or transparent border).

Draw you 50/50 gray/blue gradient in container and apply other gradient to child.
**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmkjs)**

```
/* ==========================================================================
General Award Styling
========================================================================== */
.award > span{
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;

  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* ==========================================================================
Awards Lvl1
========================================================================== */
.award_lvl1 span{
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
}
.award {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:3px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,gray 50%,turquoise 50%);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: ...  background-clip can be an option too, but will not mind the radius effect

Comment: wow, didnt thought about that simple solution :D. You are a genius :D. Thanks, exactly what i was looking for!